# What is CQL for Cassandra fetchSize

Tags: java, cassandra

I believe I have successfully implemented a Cassandra Java Integration solution, where I fetch back all of a table, in chunks, as specified by the fetch size, as described here  https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/paging/#setting-the-fetch-size

I also have the QueryLogger enabled, and I do see a CQL statement for each chunk, but it reads something like:

```
 select * from table;
```

each time. Whereas I would have expected some page / offset info to have been included, and the cql to look **something** (i.e. just for illustrative purposes, please dont take cql as syntactically correct!) like:

```
 select * from table limit 10, offset 20;
```

Is the CQL being truncated, our how is this all working? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's how the CQL is working - the query stays the same, but when the next page is retrieved, driver sends a paging state that was obtained with the previous page - it doesn't modify the query (btw, there is no such thing as `offset` in Cassandra).

Technical details [are described in the native protocol specification](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/native_protocol_v4.spec#L981), if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that clarifies the CQL question. I'm still not understanding the big picture tbh, but will reread the docs a few times and hopefully it will click. In crude terms: does this sound correct? We have an app, app db driver, and the db itself. In terms of bytes moving, the appropriate paged chunk is sent from the the db to the db driver (and on to the app) - but its not achieved (solely) via CQL, but by QUERY and  EXECUTE messages.

Comment: Basically, the Java driver docs have all details there. Although I would recommend to grab docs from one of the latest releases, like: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/paging/#setting-the-fetch-size or https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/core/paging/

Comment: Interesting, when I had a query that exceeded some time limits re SLOW query, the logger reports this query - which is more like what I would have expected to see in first place  SELECT * FROM table WHERE token(ocode) > token(21d438f2-71bf-11ea-ab85-7f77869654c1) LIMIT 10000 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)